# Probability of getting $2$ hearts, $2$ diamonds & $2$ black cards

Tags: probability

A card is drawn from a pack, the card is replaced & the pack shuffled. If this is done $6$ times, then find the probability that the cards drawn are $2$ hearts, $2$ diamonds & $2$ black cards?

I cannot think of any other method rather than making cases of sequences in which cards of drawn but that is too lengthy. Could someone please suggest some elegant method or some hint?

Can this question be assumed as "$6$ cards are drawn at random. What is the probability that they are $2$ hearts, $2$ diamonds & $2$ black cards?"

Comment: Let's assume the card are drawn in the sesired order, what is the probabiity?

Comment: @N74 But there is no desired order in the question.

Comment: Given a specific ordering of 2 hearts 2 diamonds and 2 black, the probability that six cards drawn are in that specific order (*regardless of if cards are drawn with or without replacement*) will be the same.  We can then instead of calculating each separately and adding (*remembering that it is pointless to calculate the same number multiple times in a row*) we may instead calculate the number only once and multiply by the number of arrangements of 2 hearts 2 diamonds and 2 black. After answering N74's hint, next answer the question of how many arrangements of 2hearts2diamonds2black there are

Comment: I was trying to male you think about it. When you drawn the cards you just have to shuffle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the tried and true method of counting all possible drawings of the 6 cards, then multiplying by the probability that one of these situations happens.

So we first find the number of arrangements of HHDDBB, which is $6!/2^3 = 90$, then we see that the chance of any one of these happening is $(\frac{1}{2})^{10}$.
Thus the answer is $\frac{90}{2^{10}}=\frac{45}{2^9}$.

Comment: How did you write $(1/2)^{10} $ for chance of any of these happening?

Comment: @Mathematics 1/4 is the chance for drawing a heart and for drawing a diamond. 1/2 is the chance for drawing a black. These are all independent events, so we multiply them together: $(1/4)^4 * (1/2)^2 = 1/2^{10}$